# how to rewrite plain javascript into a react component (foreach)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following  spfx component which is plain javascript and works perfectly fine.

```
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  BaseClientSideWebPart,
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';

import styles from './MyQuotesWebPart.module.scss';
import * as strings from 'MyQuotesWebPartStrings';

import { IQuotes, IQuote } from './QuoteContracts';
import { IDataReader, DataReaderFactory } from './DataReader';

export interface IMyQuotesWebPartProps {
  description: string;
}

export default class MyQuotesWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IMyQuotesWebPartProps> {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this._dataReader = DataReaderFactory.getReader(this.context);
  }

  private _dataReader : IDataReader;

  public render(): void {
    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
      <div class="${styles.myQuotes}">
        <div class="${styles.container}">
          <div class="ms-Grid-row ms-bgColor-themeDark ms-fontColor-white ${styles.row}">
            <div class="ms-Grid-col ms-lg10 ms-xl8 ms-xlPush2 ms-lgPush1">
              <span class="ms-font-xl ms-fontColor-white">Famous Quotes</span>
              <div class="ms-font-l ms-fontColor-white" id="quotesContainer"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>`;

      this.renderData();
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  private renderData(): void {
    this._dataReader.getData().then((response) => {
      this.renderQuotes(response.Quotes);
    });
  }

  private renderQuotes(items: IQuote[]): void {
    let html: string = '';
    items.forEach((item: IQuote) => {
      html += `
        <div>${escape(item.Quote)}</div>
        <div class="${styles.author}">${escape(item.Author)}</div>  
      `;
    });

    const listContainer: Element = this.domElement.querySelector('#quotesContainer');
    listContainer.innerHTML = html;
  }
}
```

And I am trying to create a react component, but I am not sure how to use the render data and how to use a foreach in the resultset received to render it, basically the question is how can Integrate it into the render method.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './Solid.module.scss';
import { ISolidProps } from './ISolidProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import { IQuotes, IQuote } from './QuoteContracts';
import { IDataReader, DataReaderFactory } from './DataReader';


export default class Solid extends React.Component<ISolidProps, {}> {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this._dataReader = DataReaderFactory.getReader(this.context);
  }

  private _dataReader : IDataReader;

  public render(): React.ReactElement<ISolidProps> {
    return (
      <div className={ styles.solid }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <div className={ styles.row }>
            <div className={ styles.column }>
              <span className={ styles.title }>Welcome to SharePoint!</span>
              <p className={ styles.subTitle }>Customize SharePoint experiences using Web Parts.</p>
              <p className={ styles.description }>{escape(this.props.description)}</p>
              <a href="https://aka.ms/spfx" className={ styles.button }>
                <span className={ styles.label }>Learn more</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Update 1:

I have my interfaces like this:

```
export interface IQuotes {
    Quotes: IQuote[];
}

export interface IQuote {
    Author: string;
    Quote: string;
}
```

Comment: You may be able to use React portals with `this.domElement`: https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the request to get the data will be asynchronous, you should make this into a member function on your React component like so:

```
fetchData = () => {
  this._dataReader.getData().then((response) => {
    this.setState({
      quotes: response.Quotes,
    });
  });
 }
```

This will trigger a render when the method is called unless you prevent an update in `shouldComponentUpdate`. We can then implement a renderMethod for the quotes:

```
renderQuotes = () => this.state.quotes.map(quote => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div>${escape(quote.Quote)}</div>
    <div class="${styles.author}">${escape(quote.Author)}</div>  
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

You don't have to use a `Fragment` as it's a part of React 16.3, it's just useful here.

Your primary render method can then render

```
<div>
  {this.renderQuotes()}
</div>
```

and in `componentDidMount` which is when you can make network requests etc. You can call `fetchData`.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchData();
}
```

Comment: what is exactly react.fragment?

Comment: Please see Update1: I have 2 errors that I am not sure how to fix: 1. Argument of type '{ quotes: IQuote[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pick<ISolidState, "quotes">'.
  Types of property 'quotes' are incompatible.
    Type 'IQuote[]' is not assignable to type 'IQuotes'.
      Property 'Quotes' is missing in type 'IQuote[]'.

Comment: and 2. [ts] Property 'map' does not exist on type 'IQuotes'.

Comment: `React.Fragment` is a new piece of react that allows you to render adjacent children without having to wrap them in a `div`. If you were to remove that, React would complain that you can only return one child element. You could change it to an array, but each item would need it's own key. Instead, react introduced the fragment component that allows this behavior without rendering extra dom nodes.